# pswa powershell web access custom configuration rules

Tags: powershell, wmi, powershell-remoting

**Goal:** Give users an account (domain user or basic, doesn't matter) and have them use Get-DhcpServerv4Lease cmdlet to convert their DHCP leases to reservations via the powershell web access feature using a web browser.

**Issue/problem:** I already made my own AuthorizationRule by importing that specific cmdlet but I feel like its missing others modules in order to authenticate/login? I can login if I grant microsoft.powershell configurationrule but cant if I grant the custom one that I made.

Error received upon login with my own custom configuration:
The Windows PowerShell Web Access gateway cannot establish a connection to the destination computer. Contact the gateway administrator. The error at the gateway is: The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The service is configured to reject remote connection requests for this plugin.

**Question:** Is there some other module I need to add to my custom rule or maybe there is a way to know what permissions microsoft.powershell contains so that I could mirror/copy them into my own rule?

***Thanks***

Comment: anyone have a clue? : )

Comment: I don't believe this is the correct place for this question. Try [sf].

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer: Remote Powershell needs to be enabled on the target system!

You can use System names, IP addresses or the FQDN. All of them will work (Use a mix as well)

To keep your Rules simple: Use Groups! Here is a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jhochwald/910300a5a9c87abfcaa48227975e4366) that could help you a bit. I have just a few rules and use AD Groups to manage the access (Systems and Users)

Please execute this (in an elevated PowerShell): `Enable-PSRemoting -Force`
You have to do this on all systems that you would like to access via the Web Gateway.

You will find a lot more Info about this on [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265971(v=ws.11).aspx).